# Define common functionality for stored procedures in one place?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Does SQL Server have an easy way to define common functionality among all/some stored procedures?

I want to log execution details (objectId, user, start, finish) for all stored procedures on a database. However, 1) I'm lazy and don't want to manually update dozens of stored procedures, and 2) if stored procedures get created in the future, I want to ensure that we don't forget to include them in the logging. My server is SQL Server 2016, and I don't have access to server-level settings, just this database.

### My use case:

First, I have a table set up for where the logging gets inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StoredProcedureExecutionLog](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Executor] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ObjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProcedureName] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ExecutionStartTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ExecutionFinishTime] [datetime2](7) NULL
)
```

Then, for every stored procedure in my database, I want to add the following 2 commands:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myStoredProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
    -- I have to add this line to the beginning of every stored procedure
    INSERT INTO dbo.StoredProcedureExecutionLog(ObjectId, ProcedureName, ExecutionStartTime, Executor) VALUES (@@PROCID, OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), GETDATE(), SYSTEM_USER)

    -- ** Stored proc code goes here **

    -- I have to add this line to the end of every stored procedure
    UPDATE dbo.StoredProcedureExecutionLog SET ExecutionFinishTime = GETDATE() WHERE Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
RETURN 0;
```

For my particular use case, I think I could even use some kind of pre- and post- signal that gets called for each stored procedure (if this kind of thing even exists in SQL Server).

Comment: SQL Server isnt an object oriented language, so it doesn't work like one. If you want to add functionality to an Procedure you need to `ALTER` it. But sounds like what you should really be doing is looking into Extended Events.

Comment: no, tsql isn't an OO programming language.  however, for newer SP, you can create a template (in ssms, click view -> template explorer) to make sure to not forget logging

Comment: Use [Extended events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15) to trace activity like this.

Comment: Even in OOP functions have no inheritance. Stored procedures are essentially methods. SQL is far closer to a *functional* than an OOP language anyway, and one could argue it's an even higher-level abstraction. What are you trying to do? Whatever it is, people had to do it in the past and database products probably have mechanisms that are *far* better than inheritance

Comment: For example `I want to log execution details (objectId, user, start, finish) for all stored procedures on a database` that's available in all database products and versions, in far more detail than any logging code would offer. It's available as tracing or profiling events. **BUT** a database serves thousands of concurrent requests per second so if you implemented naive logging code, your entire database(and application) would crawl to a halt. The built-in tracing mechanisms on all databases are far faster than any hand-written logging code.

Comment: In SQL Server, extended events are far more lightweight than previous tracing mechanisms. There are built-in ways to collect audit and trace events, batch them, etc, in order to minimise the impact on the system. `I don't have access to server-level settings, just this database.` You'll have to get the DBA to enable the necessary extended events. If you don't, you'll still have to deal with the DBA, only he/she'll be *very* angry because their system slowed to a crawl. If you have a hosted or cloud database, there are ways to enable extended events

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Agreed. However, I want to reiterate that I don't have access to any server-level settings or software. It's probably helpful to mention that this server has a relatively low load and we are only temporarily in this situation of no server settings access.

Comment: @user7733611 you'll have to deal with the DBA one way or another.What you ask is a *system*, not an application responsibility. It's already part of the database. If you get it wrong, you'll have to deal with an irrate DBA and probably very annoyed customer too.

Comment: @user7733611 the DBA is probably *already* collecting that information, just not storing it. Extended events are so lightweight that some traces are on-by-default, eg system_health. All you have to do is tell the database you need some specific events stored permanently

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't update a SP baseclass, so no you can't do that.

For the top line that needs inserting you could: SQL management studio right click the db -> Tasks ->Generate Scripts -> select all stored procs, to file.
Then write a small app (any programming language) that opens that file, looks for
`ALTER PROCEDURE` position index, then first instance of `BEGIN` then inserts your line right after that, then looks for next position of `ALTER PROCEDURE` and the next first instance of `BEGIN`...
but for the second line, I can't think of a sure way to insert into it by code...

You are probably better off biting the bullet on this one and just doing it by hand.

If you were to do that, its probably best to do all the first line for all sp's and then all the bottom lines for all sp's just because it will be slightly (perhaps 33%) more efficient for you to do this by hand if you split it that way.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the accepted answer on this link here:

[SQL-Server: Is there an equivalent of a trigger for general stored procedure execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858910/sql-server-is-there-an-equivalent-of-a-trigger-for-general-stored-procedure-exe)

You may be able to do something with a trace that allows you to capture the information you want both before and after an SP execution.

Also, take a look at using `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`.